# Can we see how often a tag is used in searches when considering burnination?

Tags: discussion, support, burninate-system

Recently I was looking at some burnination requests and the sparked discussion about the usefulness of certain tags. Often the amount of followers (usually very few) is given as a watermark for possible burnination; after all, a tag that no one looks for is useless, no matter how much questions are tagged with it.

But this made me wonder: is this really a good metric? Wouldn't it be better if instead we had a look at how often this is being used for searching? Or do both numbers usually correlate (by a simple factor or exponent)?

So the question here is: Do we have such numbers? Ideally I would like to have a table with tag name, number of searches [in the past N months], number of followers. Do we have something? I could not find anything on data.se for the searches. Do we maybe want to collect those numbers and make them a standard metric always to be considered with a burninate request?

Comment: At the very least, number of searches for a tag would be a good additional metric, even if it's not a direct replacement for number of followers.

Comment: Unfortunately searches are also a bad metric, as a number of *very bad* tags are *very generic* terms.

Comment: @Charles: But would people search for those tags or just for those keywords?

Comment: Hmm.  Good question.  To test this, we need a tag name that isn't also a searchable term...

Comment: @Charles Those tags usually get burnitated on other grounds than the amount of followers. If we would allow a [tag:google] tag for example, then surely it would pass all benchmarks for it being 'a good tag', yet it still would not be a good tag.

Comment: Not sure if the statistics are kept, but perhaps we could check out how often people do a this-tag-only search for it. And specifically for the [Tag] and not just for the tag word. I would be surprised if the query [google] is executed frequently.

Comment: Anecdotally, a number of tags that I easily could be following but am not almost always appear in concert with the one tag that I do follow, algorithm.