# Do we need the [sum] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag wiki reads

> The Sum function is used for summation of data in
>   array/table/sequence.
>   followed by examples in different languages (python,sql,c#).

The tag currently seems to have 6 followers.

We have [3584](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum) questions tagged [sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum)

- [868](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+mysql) are about [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)
- [799](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+sql) are about [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)
- [346](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+php) are about [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- [249](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+python) are about [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
- [141](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+c%23) are about [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
- [138](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+r) are about [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)
- [134](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+java) are about [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)
- [122](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+excel) are about [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)
- [111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+javascript) are about [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
- [89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+matlab) are about [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab)
- [66](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+oracle) are about [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)
- [59](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+c%2b%2b) are about [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
- [44](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+c) are about [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)
- [38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+ruby) are about [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby)
- [32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+postgresql) are about [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql)
- [29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+sqlite) are about [sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite)
- [20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+perl) are about [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl)
- [19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+bash) are about [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)
- [15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+awk) are about [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk)

[The rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+-mysql+-sql+-python+-c%23+-r+-java+-excel+-javascript+-c+-ruby+-perl+-bash+-awk+-c%2b%2b+-matlab+-postgresql+-sqlite+-oracle+-php) is about various things like other programming languages or concepts.

#### tl;dr

With 6 followers and widespread sprinkling along really useful tags like the respective language, [sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum) does not seem to be useful for searching/following. Just like for [Hello World](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254240/is-the-hello-world-tag-useful#254313) I would say there are no sum experts, people don't want to follow it and it adds nothing valuable to the question.

Comment: Seems pretty useless.

Comment: we can merge it to a tag like data manupulation or something else

Comment: @SerdarBuyuktemiz: Isn't everything we do with computers data manipulation, and thus an equally useless tag?

Comment: Would recommend replacing it with [tag:aggregate-functions] for SQL related topics(edited)

Comment: @AaronLS: that seems to only be a fit for the sql related ones.

Comment: But only for SQL related topics.  I agree sum is far too specific a tag to be useful.  In SQL the usage of sum is very similar to all other aggregate functions, so if anyone fancies themselves an expert/follower in answering those questions, then [tag:aggregate-functions] is just as effective.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yeh see second comment, didn't read through all the languages.  Another reason the sum tag is bad, as it has significantly different meanings in SQL vs programming languages

Comment: It might come in handy if we lose our calculators.

Comment: @devnull I'm sure there's a better [solution](http://www.cartoonstock.com/lowres/accountants-emergency-emergency_glass-abacus-counts-pc-sea0478l.jpg).

Comment: I would really like to meet the people who follow such a tag. Mainly to ask them *why?*

Comment: I caution hesitation, especially in more data-intensive realms such as R. Summation can actually be a tricky problem (especially when summing floating-point), and it's reasonable to have it as a tag when a meaningful language function named `sum` is involved. I agree it could use a massive pruning, but I'm against completely injudicious burnination.

Comment: @chrylis - in those cases, I'd say [tag:floating-point] is more relevant.

Comment: Couldn't this tag help a user search in combination with a language specific tag or something like [tag:floating-point]? In other words, it provides additional filtering combined with other things?

Comment: @jpmc, exactly: it works like an adverb. Alone, it's meaningless, but coupled with some other tags, it refines their meaning.

Comment: @jpmc26: To answer this, we would probably need to [implement this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253657/) somehow. I personally doubt that many people (if any at all) do a tag search for sum. Especially when searching for a way to do summation I would rather expect them to search for something like "summing up floating point numbers in r"

Comment: @PlasmaHH I suppose I started with a premise that doesn't hold up too well under scrutiny. Does anyone search directly tags at all? Most of us land on pages using Google. So a better question would be, how do tags affect Google indexing? I guess the heart of the question is, "What do tags do? How are they useful?" That would be the driving goal. I haven't been able to hunt down a good discussion of what makes a good tag, either. On the flip side of that, is it actually hurting anything by being here? It's not like some tags where it's so unclear you don't know what belongs to it.

Comment: @jpmc26: I am personally using tags to limit my searches, mostly for the desired programming language. Then I use them in things like review queues; one of the pages that opens in my browser automatically at start is [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20-qt). We really need more data about how tags are being used to tell which are useful.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I found this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/; it does a little to clarify the intention of tags. [tag:sum] probably shouldn't stand as the only tag, but I would say the same of [tag:floating-point]. Most questions appropriate for StackOverflow should have some tags related to the technology in use. [tag:sum] does tell us something about the content of a question; it just doesn't give a full picture. Meta Cooking also has some good discussion: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/455/what-is-the-purpose-of-tags-how-do-i-use-them-appropriately.

Comment: @jpmc26: "If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag. " here it sometimes means different things for different people, and what it means is sometimes clear from other tags. This probably means that we should agree on a common meaning on the sum tag (e.g. the "sum" function in the language mentioned in another tag) and that all other uses of the sum tag should be deemed wrong.

Comment: Having the sum tag makes it much easier to find questions about summation problems, rather than just those containing the word. This is convenient for finding duplicates so I would vote against removal of this tag.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: wouldn't this mean that all summation problems (regardless of the context in which summation happens) are properly tagged?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I don't the spirit of the comment regarding a tag having different meanings applies to [tag:sum]. We all know what a sum is; it's a mathematical operator with a very strict definition. Sometimes implementations vary based on the context (e.g., a `SUM` aggregate function vs a language's `+` operator), but the general concept is the same. If that's your point, though, I would argue for some kind of splitting out of `SUM`-aggregate vs. sum binary operator rather than a burninate. Even so, I'm not sure that such a split is useful or that the existing [tag:sum] is somehow harmful.