# What is the point of asking questions like "Do we need [this] tag?" if there is no action taken?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

[Do we need the [sum] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254688/do-we-need-the-sum-tag) question was asked **more than 5 years back**.

It has 39 up-votes and just 8 down-votes. I think that it is a clear idea that community think that "Sum" tag is useless. And if you see the comments of that post you can confirm that.

But still "Sum" tag is there, and there is no notice like "please don't use this tag".

Comment: [We do take action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request%20status-completed?mode=all).  It's just a painful [process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) so it can't keep up with demand.

Comment: There is a big difference between harmful tags and unnecessary tags.  There are no harmful tags left, they've been thoroughly eliminated over the past 9 years.  Something like [sum], meh, nobody ever got hurt using or reading it.  It even has followers and experts, Gordon Linoff has 293 answers.  The long tail at SO is stupendously long and the vast majority of SO users don't give a hoot about 98% of it.

Answer (score 13):

> IIt has 37 up-votes and just 5 down-votes. I think that it is a clear idea that community think that "Sum" tag is useless.

Not even close. We have a lot more than 42 users on Stack Overflow.

If there is not clear community support for burnination of a tag, then the tag remains. Apathy is never interpreted as support for a proposal, and the fact that a handful of people on Meta have upvoted a burnination proposal does not a consensus make.

There are people on Meta who will upvote virtually *any* burnination proposal simply because they enjoy burninating tags and/or because they don't personally see any merit in the tag. What that leaves out are the experts who are down "in the trenches", so to speak, providing answers to questions with that tag. If we don't ever hear from them, it's very difficult to know how that tag adds value and whether it should be kept.

This is why we have [a very specific protocol that we follow when burninating tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071), developed over time with lessons learned from past mistakes. In particular, it requires that a burnination proposal gathers some obvious support from Meta regulars, and *then* requires that the proposal be [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) with the hopes of the larger community seeing it and having the chance to weigh in.

This process isn't perfect by any stretch of the imagination. There are still tons of [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts that people miss. But it works a whole heck of a lot better than vigilante mass-retagging by users on Meta who don't have anything better to do.

So, the point of asking questions like "Do we need this tag?" is to present your *opinion* that the tag is not useful and give the opportunity for the community to chime in with their thoughts. There's no guarantee that the proposal will go anywhere from there or that any action will be taken. It's just like a feature request: some get implemented, and some don't. Some may get implemented months or years later.

If you don't see the merit in it, then don't bother to make any more proposals. If you still want to do so, then go ahead and do so. We do get around to acting on the widely-supported burnination requests eventually; [several have been carried out just in the last couple of weeks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+status-completed?sort=active&pageSize=50).

However, just because you are frustrated with the rate of progress, it is ***not acceptable*** for you to go and manually burninate a tag without following the established procedure. From my viewpoint, this is becoming distressingly common, and it needs to stop. There was a burnination proposal posted here on Meta a couple of days ago. It lasted less than an hour before someone went through and burninated the tag from all hundred or so questions. That's not okay, and I consider it to be an abuse of the system on multiple levels.

There are plenty of other productive ways to contribute to the site.

Comment: What can be seen as a "support" for burninate-request? It stated in burnination process description that "it scores at least 20". But this post has +32.. Please define rules to follow. Of course I am aware we should follow all the steps of the process, I am just asking about qualifications of "supported by community".

Comment: A burninate request becomes actionable when it has the [meta-tag:status-planned] tag attached to it.

Comment: "If we don't ever hear from them, it's very difficult to know how that tag adds value and whether it should be kept." Well, maybe we don't hear from them because they *do not exist*.

Comment: @VadimKotov support of a burnination is given when someone somewhere actually cares for the tag. The site has just too much inertia with these issues. Unless you don't have a witty title that attracts attention (and therefore popularity), it's very difficult break the inertial force that buries these request. Sometimes, you are better off not asking.

Comment: It's not inertia. It's that people fundamentally disagree about the usefulness of different tags. If nobody existed that thought the tag should be kept, the requests wouldn't be downvoted, either. But even that's not a perfectly reliable metric, since many people who answer questions don't know about Meta or don't monitor it. Choosing not to ask is fine, but choosing to go action the requests on your own is not. Do conduct a cost-benefit analysis first; burninations are not cost-free.

Comment: "It's that people fundamentally disagree about the usefulness of different tags", wat... are you being serious? I mean, I have a very strict criteria of usefulness: it has experts that actively answer the tag. That's not "subjective", nor something you can disagree with. Also, can you ping me when you respond my comments. It's very frustrating that you keep seemly addressing my points yet don't ping me. The user above is not automagically notified of newer comments.

Comment: "Do conduct a cost-benefit analysis first": lets see, questions that doesn't get closure because they use tags that nobody follows vs removing those tags and leaving only those that people actively follows. I think I did my cost-benefit analysis ages ago.